# Statistics; Normal distribution question

Tags: statistics

I'm not sure if I am solving this question correctly

A used-car dealership has found the length of time before a major repair is required on car it sells is normally distributed. Witha mean = 10 months and standard deviation of 3 months. If the dealer wants only 5% of the cars to fail before the end of the guarantee period, for how many months should the cars be guaranteed

So I use the Z value formula.  and Isolate of X

so if 5% = 0.05 I will divide by 2 so 0.025 and find the Z value which is 1.96

so 1.96 * 3 + 10 = 15.88 so the dealer wants to have 15.88 months guaranteed

Comment: I think the answer is around $5$ months, and not $15.88$ months.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x =$the length of time in months before a major repair occurs, and let $x_0 =$ the guarantee period also in months. We want : $P(x < x_0) = 0.05$, and convert to $z$ variable:

$P\left(z < \dfrac{x_0-10}{3}\right) = 0.05 \Rightarrow \dfrac{x_0-10}{3} = -1.645 \Rightarrow x_0 = 10 - 3\cdot 1.645 = 5.07 \text{ months}$.